# Retaining "md-content" scroll position between different views within "ngView"

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

I know with angularJs and using `ngView`, scroll position will retain when navigate back and forward between different views. Now I have used angular material `md-toolbar` and `md-content` directives within my views but it doesn't retain scroll position.

Is there any solution to retain scroll position of `md-content` between different views within `ngView`?

The code below will reproduce the problem and here is a plunker demo:
[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/FIzrJVfCeFAW9lsLydhI?p=preview)

index.html:

```
<body layout="row" ng-app="scrollPostion">
    <div flex layout="column" layout-fill ng-view> </div>
    <md-sidenav md-is-locked-open="true" class="md-whiteframe-z2">
        <md-list>
           <md-list-item>
               <a href="#/page1">page1</a> 
           </md-list-item>
           <md-list-item>
               <a href="#/page2">page2</a>
           </md-list-item>
        </md-list>
    </md-sidenav>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    angular
        .module('scrollPostion', ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial'])
        .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'page1.html',
            }).
                when('/page1', {
                    templateUrl: 'page1.html',
                }).
            when('/page2', {
                templateUrl: 'page2.html',
            }).
            otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' })
        }])
     </script>
</body>
```

view 1 (page1):

```
<md-toolbar layout="row" class="md-toolbar-tools">
   <h1>Page1</h1>
</md-toolbar>
<md-content flex id="content">
    <div>
      <p>long text1</p>      
    </div>
</md-content>
```

view 2 (page2):

```
<md-toolbar layout="row" class="md-toolbar-tools">
   <h1>Page2</h1>
</md-toolbar>
<md-content flex id="content">
    <div>
      <p>long text2</p>      
    </div>
</md-content>
```

I know the problem is made by `md-content` directive, because when I replace it with `div`, retaining scroll position will work but I need `md-toolbar` and `md-content` within my views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic retaining the scroll position is the job of browser and the browser only retain the scroll position of the whole page not the scroll position of inner elements of the page.

In your sample when using the `md-content` because of having `overflow:auto` and `height:100%` and `min-height:100%` the page doesn't have any scroll and as you see the scroll belongs to the `md-content` so as I said the browser can't retain the position of scroll, because the scroll belongs to an inner element.

For `div` case, because the `div` by default expand to the large content, so the scroll belongs to the page and the browser retain the scroll position.

To solve the problem:

- You can use a combination of tags and styles that makes the page scroll and gain automatic scroll position retaining.
- You also can store the scroll position of your `md-content` in your model or somewhere else and when showing the page, apply the position to your `md-content`.